# How to add other column into pgrouting query result in pgAdmin output pane?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, windows-8, pgadmin-3

I'm working on my final research project now and I'm a new user in pgrouting. Is there any chances to add another column name to display in the output pane? I'd like to add road name column so that I can easily know the road, for the final result I'll build a web app[image: here the screenshot of my pgAdmin window query result using A*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pgRouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html) gives a simple example how to return the path geometries. But this would work in the same way for any other attribute:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, b.the_geom FROM pgr_dijkstra('
                SELECT gid AS id,
                         source::integer,
                         target::integer,
                         length::double precision AS cost
                        FROM ways',
                30, 60, false, false) a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.id2 = b.gid);
```

Comment: thanks! I'm able to visualize the result by using "Store the result as table" described in the pgROuting workshop and adding the layer to QGIS 2.0. But when I tried the "Use QGIS SQL where clause when adding a PostGIS layer" it gave me an error message in "LINE 1" near "gid", I'm using pgrouting 2.0 postgis 2.1 and postgresql 9.3 on windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: The workshop was primarily tested with the recent version of OSGeo LiveDVD, which runs PostgreSQL 9.1, PostGIS 2.0 and QGIS 2.0. There might be an issue with different versions, but I have no clue where the problem could be. On my local Ubuntu installation the workshop queries are also no problem.

Comment: The workshop also mentions QGIS DB Manager Plugin, which should work with any query that contains a geometry in the result set.

Comment: from the pgRouting workshop does it use the road network from OSM @dkastl ? If I want to use my own data stored in PostgreSQL using the same step in pgRouting workshop is that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but you may need to change ID's in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. that SELECT gid as gid .... is the magic part.If you have have "name" column in your table you can just add `SELECT gid as gid, name as road_name ... FROM tablex` if your name column is on another table then you need to to something like this. `SELECT a.gid as gid , b.name as name ... FROM tablex as a , nametable as b WHERE a.gid = b.gid` (or you can do JOIN ). you anly needuse table alias ehn both tables have same column name.

See [documention](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/index.html) and [howto query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/queries.html)

Comment: The road name column is "ujung_jala" and the type of the column is "character varying" I add "ujung_jala AS road_name" to the SQL command using dijkstra but the result table still not showing the road_name column, am I doing a mistake?

Comment: I add name as road_name but the column still not displayed @simplexio , do you have suggestion?